# C# says that A is not an instance of B yet A implements interface B

Tags: c#, plugins, dll, interface, polymorphism

Problem - I am trying my hand at plugIn development and all is going well except where trying to cast object A to object B even though A implements B.

Interface:

```
namespace DynamicApplications
{
    public interface IPlugIn
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
        IPlugInHost myHost { set; }
        void Show();
    }

    public interface IPlugInHost
    {
        bool Register(IPlugIn plug);
    }
}
```

Class which Implements `IPlugIn`

```
namespace plugInOne
{
    class PlugIn : IPlugIn
    {
        IPlugInHost _myHost;

        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return "Plug-In One";
            }
            set
            {
            }
        }

        public IPlugInHost myHost
        {
            set
            {
                _myHost = value;
            }
        }

        public void Show()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

And now THE CODE for the instantiation:

```
        String path = Application.StartupPath;
        string[] assemblyNames = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.dll");
        plugs = new IPlugIn[assemblyNames.Length];

        for(int i = 0; i < assemblyNames.Length; i++)
        {
            string Name = assemblyNames[i];
            Name = Name.Substring(Name.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1, Name.Length - Name.LastIndexOf("\\") - 1);
            Name = Name.Remove(Name.LastIndexOf(".dll"));
            assemblyNames[i] = Name;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < assemblyNames.Length; i++)
        {
            Assembly DLL = Assembly.Load(assemblyNames[i]);

            if(DLL != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    Object p = Activator.CreateInstance(DLL.GetType(assemblyNames[i] + ".PlugIn"));

                    if (p is DynamicApplications.IPlugIn)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("YES!!!!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("no>?>?>>><<?????");
                    }

                    plugs[i] = (IPlugIn)p;
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

Note the debugger shows that `p` is in fact instantiated and accessible

The Application always hits `MessageBox.Show("no>?>?>>><<?????");`

Help Please

Aiden

**EDIT**

P is of Type:

[image: P is of Type:]
Also

[image]

YET plugInOne.PlugIn implements IPlugIn

Comment: Have your messagebox show what type `p` is.  Once you know that, you probably don't need more help.

Comment: You seem to be referencing different assemblies. Common mistake.

Comment: I (1) put the interface and instantiation code in a console app, (2) referenced the console app from a class library and put the implementation in the library, (3) built the library and put the DLL in the console app's folder, (4) ran the console app and the consoel equivalent of `MessageBox.Show("YES!!!!");` _did_ fire. In _principle_ you're doing nothing wong; in _practice_ maybe your DLL isn't there, or is out of date, or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your referencing a `DynamicApplications.IPlugIn` and that is not the same interface which will be contained in the assembly.

You need to get your `IPlugin` instance from your assembly instead of using a local instance. Your code for checking is fine, if you did something like this:

```
public interface IA { }
public class A :IA { }


object a = Activator.CreateInstance<A>();
if (a is IA)
    Console.WriteLine("Yes");
```

However you are getting your `A` (in the above context) from somewhere else, and still trying to reference your local version of `IA` - therefore you need to get your interface from your assembly instead of trying to reference it locally. Perhaps you could do something like this:

```
if (objA.GetType().GetInterfaces().Any(x => x.Name == "IA"))
  Console.WriteLine("Yes");
```

Comment: Ok holnd on quickly - i am confused. I instantiate an object of Type `plugInOne.PlugIn` which implements `DynamicApplications.IPlugIn` and then test if the instantiated object is of type `DynamicApplications.IPlugIn` (which it should be since thats the way i coded it).

Sorry but please explain some more

Comment: o and ps. `if (objA.GetType().GetInterfaces().Any(x => x.Name == "IA"))
  Console.WriteLine("Yes");` passes

Comment: You are instansiating a `type` from an assembly and then checking if the type you have instansiated implements a **LOCAL** version of an interface, the `type` from the assembly will implement the assemblies version of the interface not the local version because it knows nothing about it.

Comment: @LukeHennerley What makes you think there is a local version of the interface? (Edit: Maybe that comment that says the name check passes, I guess...)

Comment: @LukeHennerley - it took me a while but finally figured out what you meant. Kudos mate !

Comment: @AidenStrydom Not a problem, usually the simplest problems are the longest to get your head around.